# Which event log file does IIS 7 app pool log to

Tags: iis7

Which event log files does the IIS 7.0 Application Pool Recycling log to?
I want to check out at what time the default app pool automatically recylces.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

It is definitely **System Log**.

**Which Log file?** Well -- you can check the physical path by right clicking on the System Log (e.g. Server Manager | Diagnostics | Event Viewer | Windows Logs). The default physical path is `%SystemRoot%\System32\Winevt\Logs\System.evtx`.

You can create a **Custom Filter** and filter by "Source: WAS" to quickly see only entries generated by IIS.

You may need first to enable logging of such even for a specific App Pool -- by default App Pool has only 3 recycle events out of 8 enabled. To change it using GUI: II S Manager | Application Pools | Select App Pool -> Advanced Settings | Generate Recycle Event Log Entry.